# Show all apps installed, and show GridView with ViewPager (Like in android home screen)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have been trying to make an app which shows all installed application in view pager like in android phones.

where 4x4 grid view is shown and new grid fragment is added automatically to add more applications when needed.

i hope you understand what i am trying to say.

http://shrikantsonarblogs.blogspot.in/2013/07/gridview-with-viewpager-like-android.html

i tried this but when i add installed app icons in the base adapter ,the icons repeat showing same icons in very page.

Please help, i have tried a lot and lost many days on this.Thank you so so much in advance.

Code from Activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager awesomePager;
    private PagerAdapter pm;
    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<Category> codeCategory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // mIndicator = (PagerIndicator) findViewById(R.id.pagerIndicator);

        PackageManager pmManager = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> list = pmManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {

            results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pmManager).toString());

            // results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
            // Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
            // .loadLabel(pmManager).toString());
        }

        Collections.sort(results);
        String[] myArray = results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);

        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

        Category m = new Category();

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            a.add(i, myArray[i]);
            m.name = a.get(i);
        }    

        codeCategory = new ArrayList<Category>();
        codeCategory.add(m);

        Iterator<String> it = a.iterator();

        List<GridFragment> gridFragments = new ArrayList<GridFragment>();
        it = a.iterator();
        int i = 0;

        while (it.hasNext()) {

            ArrayList<GridItems> itmLst = new ArrayList<GridItems>();

            GridItems itm = new GridItems(0, it.next());
            itmLst.add(itm);
            i = i + 1;

            if (it.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm1 = new GridItems(1, it.next());
                itmLst.add(itm1);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            if (it.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm2 = new GridItems(2, it.next());
                itmLst.add(itm2);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            if (it.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm3 = new GridItems(3, it.next());
                itmLst.add(itm3);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            if (it.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm4 = new GridItems(4, it.next());
                itmLst.add(itm4);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            if (it.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm5 = new GridItems(5, it.next());
                itmLst.add(itm5);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            if (it.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm6 = new GridItems(6, it.next());
                itmLst.add(itm6);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            if (it.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm7 = new GridItems(7, it.next());
                itmLst.add(itm7);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            if (it.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm8 = new GridItems(8, it.next());
                itmLst.add(itm8);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            GridItems[] gp = {};
            GridItems[] gridPage = itmLst.toArray(gp);
            gridFragments.add(new GridFragment(gridPage, MainActivity.this));
        }

        pm = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), gridFragments);
        awesomePager.setAdapter(pm);
        // mIndicator.setViewPager(awesomePager);

    }


    //FragmentStatePagerAdapter Class

    private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private List<GridFragment> fragments;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<GridFragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
package com.example.pagedgridviewexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Drawable> cacheArrayList = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

    Drawable[] somedrawable;

    public class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textTitle;    
    }

    private GridItems[] items;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, GridItems[] locations) {

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
        items = locations;

        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
           // cacheArrayList.add((String) packageInfo.loadLabel(pm));
           cacheArrayList.add(packageInfo.loadIcon(pm));
        }          

        somedrawable = new Drawable[cacheArrayList.size()];       
        somedrawable = cacheArrayList.toArray(somedrawable); 
    }

    public GridItems[] getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(GridItems[] items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        if (items != null) {
            return items.length;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        if (items != null && position >= 0 && position < getCount()) {
            return items[position];
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        if (items != null && position >= 0 && position < getCount()) {
            return items[position].id;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void setItemsList(GridItems[] locations) {
        this.items = locations;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (view == null) {

            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridrow, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            viewHolder.textTitle = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        GridItems gridItems = items[position];
        setCatImage(position, viewHolder, gridItems.title);
        return view;
    }

    private void setCatImage(int pos, ViewHolder viewHolder, String catTitle) {

        // ResolveInfo info = this.mApps.get(pos);
        viewHolder.textTitle.setText(catTitle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution that shows how to list information from the app installed

see more here : http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon

```
class PInfo {

    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;

   private void prettyPrint() {
        Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
    }
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {

    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */

    final int max = apps.size();

    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
    }
    return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {

    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {

        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);

        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }

        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Comment: sorry bro this not the code for me, i was searching for the paged grid view showing all installed like we get in a normal android phone launcher.

Comment: But that is exactly what the above code does, lists all installed applications, now if you just want a home screen, you can take home sample application available on the platform as an example.

Answer (score 0):

In Your MainActivity add results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName.toString()); instead of results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pmManager).toString()) to pass the PackageName to the adapter.

And in the Adapter -

Create a String Arraylist for the Package Labels along with cacheArrayList

In the menthod, public GridAdapter(Context context, GridItems[] locations) {}, get the Labels and Icons and add it to the String Array List for Labels and cacheArrayList respectively.

Get those from your getView method and populate.

Hope this helps